# How to get rid of text overlapping with the arrow buttons when filtered in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When filtering, my header columns are overlapped by the arrow buttons as in the below snapshot.

How can I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: You could perhaps increase the cell height and format the text to be right aligned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a different solution to this that may be preferable to some.

There is no reason why the filter has to go on the same row as the header label. So we can simply add in another row under our header to put the filter on, avoiding any overlap with the text in our header row.

With some quick formatting work, we end up with:

[image]

Note that I moved the column labels on the right that were not displayed clockwise down to the new row, and erased the border between the old and new row.

Comment: I love your solution and get it as accepted immediately ^^ Thank you!

Comment: This does seem pretty great. Step-by-step instructions would be nice, though. I'm on Excel for Mac 16.03 and can't figure out how to do it. I created a new row above the filters (which were created automatically by formatting as a table), but when I try to delete the text from the filters row, it keeps reappearing as Column 1, Column 2, etc. And even when I replace that with " ", it puts in a 2, 3, etc. after the space. I guess what I'll do is put the header text back in that row and color it the same color as the background.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing you can do to push the buttons into the background. Format the cells to be top-aligned, or add a few spaces before the text in each cell.

Top aligned looks like this:

[image]

Spaces added in front of the text look like this:

[image]